# How to not let the zipcode comes in google placesapi auto-suggestion

Tags: google-places-api

i'm facing problem with google places api.

When I input "new delhi" it shows "New Delhi, Delhi 110001, India " on my site page : https://www.fabstage.com/professionals/  . But on any other site it shows 
"New Delhi, Delhi, India ". And this happens only for this location(new delhi).
check here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I want same input because it's not getting correct result for location search query. Please help.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKvFWo1zxb71vCtFRIq2z4oz2h5EEZYPQ&v=3.exp&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" class="autocomplete form-control" id="search_city" placeholder="Input City Location">
<script type="text/javascript">
var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete')[0];
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mydiv, 'click', function(){
var options = {
    types: ['(regions)']
};
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete')[0];
if(input){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var dat = autocomplete.getPlace();
        $("#search_city").val(dat.formatted_address);
        /***On keyup event**/
        var input_data = dat.formatted_address;
        var path = $('#path').val();
        var path = $('#main_path').val();
        if(input_data) {
            var checkPath = path.substr(path.length - 1);
            if(checkPath == '/') {
                var new_href = path+'city/'+input_data.toLowerCase()
                        .replace(/ /g,'-')
                        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
            }else {
                var new_href = path+'/city/'+input_data.toLowerCase()
                        .replace(/ /g,'-')
                        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
            }

        } else {
            var new_href = path;
        }
        $('#find_city').attr('href', new_href);

    });
}
});

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the docs the Google maps api has different options for results to be returned.  The example that you have referenced only uses places for autocomplete.  If you only want places and not addresses make sure you have set the Google maps api set to only return places.

EDIT:

After inspecting the results of the http request on your site and the plunker the same json object is returned.  They both contain the same value for formatted address.

```
"formatted_address" : "New Delhi, Delhi 110001, India",
```

However, the code you have provided modifies the formatted address to get rid of the zip code.  So I would check to make sure your site is doing the same thing.

Comment: but the zipcode is visible only for 1 location input "new delhi" . for any other imput it works fine without zipcode.

Comment: Not able to replicate your problem.    https://plnkr.co/edit/CIBt4UVa9Uoj5HffnmXt?p=preview

Comment: yes, you are right . in code snippet its working fine. then why its not working fine on my site ? try on this page , in city feild : https://www.fabstage.com/professionals/    and write " new delhi "

Comment: after writing choose the "new delhi, delhi, india" from auto-suggestion . it shows fine but after choosing it changes to "New Delhi, Delhi 110001, India "